# redim rows a dynamic array gives a type mismatch error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```
Option Base 1

Sub ReDimRows()
Dim WF As WorksheetFunction
Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim MyArray() As Variant

MyArray = Range("A1:B11")

MyArray = ReDimRow(MyArray, 1) ' type mismatch occurs here

End Sub

Public Function ReDimRow(TargetArray() As Variant, r As Long) As Variant

TargetArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TargetArray)

ReDim Preserve TargetArray(UBound(TargetArray, 1), UBound(TargetArray, 2) + r)

TargetArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TargetArray)

End Function
```

Comment: in your function, at the end of the function line make it `Variant()` And do not forget to add the return as the last line: `ReDimRow = TargetArray`

Comment: Also, one note:  WorksheetFunction.Transpose has a limit.  If you reach that limit you may want to iterate the array and transpose manually.

Comment: You might find it convenient, but `Option Base 1` is probably best avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Other suggestions have also been taken on board.